# Python script running 'subprocess' using a lot of cpu on Rapsberry Pi Zero

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, subprocess, cpu-usage, solar

I have a short python script that monitors the battery voltage of a solar folding project I'm running, and shuts off the Pi if the battery voltage drops below a certain threshold.
The problem is that the script is using a constant 60-65% of the Pi Zero's only core.
I also have Grafana and a small script that enters values into a database running on the Pi, but these are only sipping 2-5% sporadically.
The system works fine, but I don't understand why the script with *subprocess* is using so much cpu.
Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
from ina219 import INA219, DeviceRangeError
from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

SHUNT_OHMS = 0.1
MAX_EXPECTED_AMPS = 3.19

ina40 = INA219(SHUNT_OHMS, MAX_EXPECTED_AMPS, address=0x40)
ina40.configure(ina40.RANGE_32V)

while True:
   v40 = ina40.voltage()
   print(v40)
   if v40 < 19:
      subprocess.call(["shutdown", "-h", "now"])
      sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're asking the pi to keep checking the voltage as fast as it can so it will use as much CPU as it needs.

Just put a short sleep eg. `sleep(0.1)` at the end of the loop and it will cut down the CPU usage dramatically.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There is a sleep(5) at the end of the code. Shouldn't this have the same effect?

Looking at it again, I'm wondering if my sleep(5) isn't actually doing anything, as it's in the "if" clause.

Comment: I added a sleep(1) after "print(v40), and it seems to have done the trick. Thank you @cguk70

Comment: That's right. If your intention was to run the check every 5 seconds then just shift the indentation to the left so it is outside the if statement. I thought perhaps that sleep was there to give the shutdown command time to run?

Comment: I think I just placed the sleep(5) in the wrong place, but I'll leave it where it is in case it operates like you say as a delay for the shutdown command.